# MudTable Default SelectedItem

Tags: mudblazor

I am trying to setup a table from MudBlazor (MudTable) with single row select but I can't seem to find a way on how I could set the default item value. The code I have is fairly similar to [this example in their website](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#click-event-and-display-for-selected-row). Except on how I load the data, I am using **ServerData** property instead of **Items**.

Tried adding something like on "OnAfterRender", "OnInitialized", etc... but no luck.

```
protected override OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    table.SelectedItem = MyDesiredDefaultValue;
    //or
    table.SetSelectedItem(MyDesiredDefaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `StateHasChanged` call to your code.

## Example

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        table.SelectedItem = MyDesiredDefaultValue;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

## Demo

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cummYIPSLfOzxLxx